# I am trying to turn named ranges into named tables while keeping Auto populating headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with 32 individual named ranges and the Section Title (B338 for example) is linked to the equivalent value in the Table of Contents (B70 for example).  What I would like to do is to turn those 32 individually named ranges into 32 individually named tables, while keeping the auto populating Section Headers (my assignment is to make it as automated as possible).  Every time I go to convert a range to a table, Excel informs me that it cannot keep the formula.  So I can either keep the named ranges as is and band each other row manually and keep the automation for the Section Headers, or I can settle and turn them all into tables and lose that aspect of automation.  I would like to combine the two (automatic population of Section Headers and automatic banding of rows), however I am not sure it is possible.